# Kitchen receptacle sparked and now has no power

Tags: electrical, kitchens

My Aunt plugged in a device and the receptacle sparked. Now she has no power. The breaker did not trip and the GFI will not reset.

Comment: This is likely an outlet that has broken inside and caused arcing that led to a high resistance short inside the outlet. The loss of power in the outlet is going to be due to the GFI detecting the fault and cutting off the load side outlets. Best is to follow Speedy's advice and get in a qualified electrician.

Answer (score 3):

Without any kind of electrical knowledge or experience, a tripped breaker or GFI are the two things to check.

From my perspective calling an electrician is the safest bet at this point. Especially considering the receptacle sparked. She needs to get this checked out.